# Can curl decompress a local file it already downloaded?

Tags: linux, compression, curl

I tried downloading the source code of a web page using `curl`. The resulting file appears to contain "random" characters; in fact it is a compressed version of the html code. I know that because adding the `--compressed` option, i.e.

```
curl --compressed https://example.com
```

results in the correct (decompressed) html code.

I would like to decompress the file I first downloaded, but was not able to do it using `7z`, `gzip`, `gunzip`, `zstd`, nor `brotli`. None of those tools seems to recognize the file as an archive (perhaps a header is missing?).

I guess `curl` should be able to decompress it, since that is what it does on the fly when using `--compressed`. From the `curl` man page:

> --compressed Request a compressed response using one of the algorithms curl supports, and automatically decompress the content. Headers are not  modified.

I have tried things along the lines of

```
curl --compressed file:///path/to/compressed/file --output decompressed.html
```

but no luck so far.

Do you have any idea of which command line I could use (with or without `curl`)?

Comment: Odd. You can check the headers and see if that gives you a hint about compression format. Typically for web servers Gzip is what is used to compress content. The Curl command to check headers is this: `curl -ILk https://example.com`. The breakdown is the `I` tells it to return only headers, `L` tells Curl to follow redirects and the `k` tells Curl to ignore HTTPS errors that might pop up when attempting to connect via HTTPS without a CA being verifiable.

Comment: Try with `file`. It can identify just about anything.

Comment: @Daniel B - `file` replies: data

Answer (score 0):

Run `curl -i <url>` and look at the headers.

One common HTTP compression method is `Content-Encoding: deflate`, which is exactly the same algorithm as gzip (and usually handled by the same *zlib* library) but using a different framing (defined in RFC 1950 instead of RFC 1952) that the file-oriented `gzip` CLI tool does not support.

Use either [zpipe.c](https://zlib.net/zpipe.c) from zlib, or something like Python's `zlib.decompressobj()` to handle this format.

Comment: So far I tried the Python way.
`zdec = zlib.decompressobj();
result = zdec.decompress(binary_file_content)`
produces an error: `zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check`

Comment: In theory yes, in practice I specifically used `-i` for my tests to make sure the website doesn't change its answers between HEAD and GET, as while against the standards it's still something I've seen CGI-based sites do.